# What area of effect does the Siren skill Ruin have?

Tags: borderlands-2

The description for the Sirens Ruin skill (the last skill of the Cataclysm tree) says "Phaselock now Slags, Electrocutes, and Corrodes **all nearby enemies**."

I haven't been able to figure out where the "nearby" is exactly, is it enemies near the phaselocked enemy or enemies close to your character? In either case, what is the range  for "nearby".

I've tried playing around with it, but can't figure out either of these questions.

Comment: I'd roughly estimate it at 3-4 meters in diameter or so, Keith's answer has the practical detail is though. You'll get a feel for it as you use it. It's definitely targets near the target, not you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's range is visible - once you have *Ruin* you'll see coloured tendrils that extend from the phaselock sphere, about the same again as the diameter of the sphere (though that varies by enemy size and the tendrils don't). Anything in that area gets the elemental effect.

Combine with a singularity grenade (slag or electrical to 'soften up') or the *Converge* skill to own large groups of enemies. Both effects pull enemies close enough for *Ruin* to hit them.

Comment: Ruin and Converge are a great combo. I just wish the Shock burst fired first, not the Fire; gotta crack those Shields.

Comment: @BenBrocka electrical singularity grenade mod - kills most of the shields, then phaselock one of them. I don't think the fire damage is part if _Ruin_, I think that's from another skill.

Comment: Yeah, it's from Helios, but it has a similar effect; I just meant it's damage would be optimized if it happened *after* Ruin

Answer (score 1):

It applies to the enemies near the phaselock.

To know the exact range is very though, but personal experience says its not very large, basically what is standing next to the phaselocked mob.